# Synaptic Loading/Running Slowly

Tags: apt, synaptic

Synaptic has been running extremely slow lately, it's been taking ages to start up and goes dark (what an program does when it's not responding). After installing stuff, it goes dark again, and usually crashes.

Another thing I realised is when marking packages, when a dialog box comes up saying something like: "These other packages will be installed as well cause the package you wanna install depends on them", each package renames and turns into a list of all the packages in alphabetical descending order until I put my moues over one and it turns back to its original name:

Example:
[image: Example of what I said above]

Does anyone know what this is cause by or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Remove apt-xapian-index and maybe you'll see some improvement after that. Code is: **sudo apt-get remove apt-xapian-index**. You can also remove this package from inside Synaptic. After you remove it, you have to use the search button to look for your software but it should work faster than before.

Comment: Thanks. Using the interface is much faster, but it doesn't speed up the slow loading time and having the use the button to search is a hassle.

Comment: Without apt-xapian-index your search results are more reliable than before. As for the loading speed it has nothing to do with synaptic, it seems like you have an older cpu which responds in its own fashion to your abusive treatment :). You should consider installing xubuntu-desktop to be able to boot into a lighter session, more cpu friendly. Codes are: sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop and sudo apt-get install xfce4* . After reboot choose the XFCE session or Xubuntu session to be able to run a faster Ubuntu with fewer resource usage.

Comment: Thanks. I feel its a bug though. Although there's not much to say, it definitely launched much faster before than now.

Comment: If you just installed Ubuntu 14.04, I can't say much about it, never tested it. You're not the only one complaining, I have read many other posts with different issues than yours, and it looks like Ubuntu 14.04 still needs a lot of work to be done.

Comment: What about the "Another thing"? It is not related to a slow CPU, the UI refresh after operation with the original Synaptic list of all package and when you hover the list by mouse, the previous list (of search term) appears one by one.